# JavaScript anonymous function syntax

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

The following syntax is present in a .js file.

```
var fun1 = function(fun1_parameter1){
  return{
    fun2 : function(){
      alert("xxx");
    }
  }
}
```

I am not getting this at all. 
This js file uses namespaces also.
Help me understanding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What that code does is define a single variable named `fun1`.

The value is an anonymous function with one parameter.

Calling the function would return an anonymous object with a `.fun2` property, which points to *another* anonymous function.

Calling *that* function would trigger the `alert`:

```
 fun1(0).fun2(); // triggers alert("xxx")
```

Comment: You could also omit the unused argument to fun1: `fun1().fun2();`